# Point Cloud Library (PCL) basic tutorial cmake and make errors on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, c++, make, cmake

I've been trying to get PCL (1.8) working properly on my system (Ubuntu 16.04) but I am struggling to get even the basic tutorial to work. I could not install the prebuilt [binaries](http://pointclouds.org/downloads/linux.html) supplied by pointclouds.org so instead followed the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711172/pcl-point-cloud-library-1-7-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-build-error) post over on stack overflow and used the native [repository](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/pcl) from Ubuntu to install v1.8.

I then began to run into the same issues raised in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369369/compiling-pcl-1-7-on-ubuntu-16-04-errors-in-cmake-generated-makefile) question. I fixed some of them myself using symlinks to correct paths broken by renaming and also installed the missing packages that I could. However I am unable to successfully create a usable makefile.

I am trying to follow [this](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/using_pcl_pcl_config.php#using-pcl-pcl-config) tutorial from pointclouds.org just so I can make sure everything is working.

Output from running `cmake`:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.3
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.3
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Checking for module 'eigen3'
--   Found eigen3, version 3.2.92
-- Found eigen: /usr/include/eigen3  
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   filesystem
--   thread
--   date_time
--   iostreams
--   serialization
--   chrono
--   atomic
--   regex
-- Checking for module 'libopenni'
--   Found libopenni, version 1.5.4.0
-- Found openni: /usr/lib/libOpenNI.so  
-- Checking for module 'libopenni2'
--   Found libopenni2, version 2.2.0.3
-- Found OpenNI2: /usr/lib/libOpenNI2.so  
** WARNING ** io features related to pcap will be disabled
** WARNING ** io features related to png will be disabled
-- The imported target "vtkRenderingPythonTkWidgets" references the file
   "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkRenderingPythonTkWidgets.so"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   "/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-6.2/VTKTargets.cmake"
but not all the files it references.

-- Found libusb-1.0: /usr/include  
-- looking for PCL_COMMON
-- Found PCL_COMMON: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcl_common.so  
-- looking for PCL_OCTREE
-- Found PCL_OCTREE: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcl_octree.so  
-- looking for PCL_IO
-- Found PCL_IO: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcl_io.so  
-- Found PCL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_date_time.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_iostreams.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_serialization.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_chrono.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_atomic.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so;optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcl_common.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcl_common.so;optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcl_octree.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcl_octree.so;/usr/lib/libOpenNI.so;/usr/lib/libOpenNI2.so;vtkImagingStencil;vtkCommonComputationalGeometry;vtkCommonDataModel;vtkCommonMath;vtkCommonCore;vtksys;vtkCommonMisc;vtkCommonSystem;vtkCommonTransforms;vtkImagingCore;vtkCommonExecutionModel;vtkFiltersAMR;vtkFiltersGeneral;vtkFiltersCore;vtkParallelCore;vtkIOLegacy;vtkIOCore;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so;vtkInteractionWidgets;vtkFiltersHybrid;vtkImagingSources;vtkRenderingCore;vtkCommonColor;vtkFiltersExtraction;vtkFiltersStatistics;vtkImagingFourier;vtkalglib;vtkFiltersGeometry;vtkFiltersSources;vtkFiltersModeling;vtkImagingGeneral;vtkImagingHybrid;vtkIOImage;vtkDICOMParser;vtkmetaio;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so;vtkInteractionStyle;vtkRenderingAnnotation;vtkImagingColor;vtkRenderingFreeType;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so;vtkftgl;vtkRenderingVolume;vtkIOParallelNetCDF;vtkParallelMPI;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdf_c++.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdf.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/lib/libhdf5.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsz.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/lib/libhdf5_hl.so;vtkRenderingOpenGL;vtkIOLSDyna;vtkIOXML;vtkIOGeometry;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjsoncpp.so;vtkIOXMLParser;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so;vtkLocalExample;vtkInfovisCore;vtkGeovisCore;vtkInfovisLayout;vtkViewsCore;vtkproj4;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so;vtkTestingGenericBridge;/usr/lib/libgl2ps.so;verdict;vtkIOMovie;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtheoraenc.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtheoradec.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so;vtkFiltersImaging;vtkIOMINC;vtkRenderingLOD;vtkViewsQt;vtkGUISupportQt;vtkViewsInfovis;vtkChartsCore;vtkRenderingContext2D;vtkRenderingLabel;vtkRenderingImage;vtkFiltersFlowPaths;vtkxdmf2;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so;vtkFiltersReebGraph;vtkViewsContext2D;vtkIOXdmf2;vtkIOAMR;vtkRenderingContextOpenGL;vtkImagingStatistics;vtkIOParallel;vtkFiltersParallel;vtkIONetCDF;vtkexoIIc;vtkGUISupportQtOpenGL;vtkIOParallelLSDyna;vtkFiltersParallelGeometry;vtkGUISupportQtWebkit;vtkIOPLY;vtkWrappingTools;vtkFiltersHyperTree;vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL;vtkIOExodus;vtkIOPostgreSQL;vtkIOSQL;sqlite3;vtkWrappingJava;vtkFiltersParallelFlowPaths;vtkFiltersParallelStatistics;vtkFiltersProgrammable;vtkFiltersParallelImaging;vtkRenderingParallelLIC;vtkRenderingLIC;vtkInteractionImage;vtkFiltersPython;vtkWrappingPythonCore;vtkIOParallelExodus;vtkFiltersGeneric;vtkIOVideo;vtkRenderingQt;vtkFiltersTexture;vtkIOInfovis;vtkGUISupportQtSQL;vtkRenderingFreeTypeOpenGL;vtkInfovisBoostGraphAlgorithms;vtkRenderingGL2PS;vtkIOGeoJSON;vtkFiltersVerdict;vtkViewsGeovis;vtkIOImport;vtkTestingIOSQL;vtkPythonInterpreter;vtkIOODBC;vtkIOEnSight;vtkIOMySQL;vtkRenderingMatplotlib;vtkDomainsChemistry;vtkIOExport;vtkFiltersParallelMPI;vtkIOParallelXML;vtkTestingRendering;vtkIOMPIParallel;vtkParallelMPI4Py;vtkFiltersSMP;vtkFiltersSelection;vtkIOVPIC;VPIC;vtkImagingMath;vtkImagingMorphological;vtkRenderingParallel;vtkRenderingFreeTypeFontConfig;vtkIOFFMPEG;vtkIOMPIImage;vtkIOGDAL;optimized;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcl_io.so;debug;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcl_io.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_date_time.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_iostreams.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_serialization.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_chrono.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_atomic.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_regex.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so;/usr/lib/libOpenNI.so;/usr/lib/libOpenNI2.so;vtkImagingStencil;vtkCommonComputationalGeometry;vtkCommonDataModel;vtkCommonMath;vtkCommonCore;vtksys;vtkCommonMisc;vtkCommonSystem;vtkCommonTransforms;vtkImagingCore;vtkCommonExecutionModel;vtkFiltersAMR;vtkFiltersGeneral;vtkFiltersCore;vtkParallelCore;vtkIOLegacy;vtkIOCore;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so;vtkInteractionWidgets;vtkFiltersHybrid;vtkImagingSources;vtkRenderingCore;vtkCommonColor;vtkFiltersExtraction;vtkFiltersStatistics;vtkImagingFourier;vtkalglib;vtkFiltersGeometry;vtkFiltersSources;vtkFiltersModeling;vtkImagingGeneral;vtkImagingHybrid;vtkIOImage;vtkDICOMParser;vtkmetaio;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so;vtkInteractionStyle;vtkRenderingAnnotation;vtkImagingColor;vtkRenderingFreeType;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so;vtkftgl;vtkRenderingVolume;vtkIOParallelNetCDF;vtkParallelMPI;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdf_c++.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdf.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/lib/libhdf5.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsz.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/lib/libhdf5_hl.so;vtkRenderingOpenGL;vtkIOLSDyna;vtkIOXML;vtkIOGeometry;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjsoncpp.so;vtkIOXMLParser;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so;vtkLocalExample;vtkInfovisCore;vtkGeovisCore;vtkInfovisLayout;vtkViewsCore;vtkproj4;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so;vtkTestingGenericBridge;/usr/lib/libgl2ps.so;verdict;vtkIOMovie;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtheoraenc.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtheoradec.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so;vtkFiltersImaging;vtkIOMINC;vtkRenderingLOD;vtkViewsQt;vtkGUISupportQt;vtkViewsInfovis;vtkChartsCore;vtkRenderingContext2D;vtkRenderingLabel;vtkRenderingImage;vtkFiltersFlowPaths;vtkxdmf2;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so;vtkFiltersReebGraph;vtkViewsContext2D;vtkIOXdmf2;vtkIOAMR;vtkRenderingContextOpenGL;vtkImagingStatistics;vtkIOParallel;vtkFiltersParallel;vtkIONetCDF;vtkexoIIc;vtkGUISupportQtOpenGL;vtkIOParallelLSDyna;vtkFiltersParallelGeometry;vtkGUISupportQtWebkit;vtkIOPLY;vtkWrappingTools;vtkFiltersHyperTree;vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL;vtkIOExodus;vtkIOPostgreSQL;vtkIOSQL;sqlite3;vtkWrappingJava;vtkFiltersParallelFlowPaths;vtkFiltersParallelStatistics;vtkFiltersProgrammable;vtkFiltersParallelImaging;vtkRenderingParallelLIC;vtkRenderingLIC;vtkInteractionImage;vtkFiltersPython;vtkWrappingPythonCore;vtkIOParallelExodus;vtkFiltersGeneric;vtkIOVideo;vtkRenderingQt;vtkFiltersTexture;vtkIOInfovis;vtkGUISupportQtSQL;vtkRenderingFreeTypeOpenGL;vtkInfovisBoostGraphAlgorithms;vtkRenderingGL2PS;vtkIOGeoJSON;vtkFiltersVerdict;vtkViewsGeovis;vtkIOImport;vtkTestingIOSQL;vtkPythonInterpreter;vtkIOODBC;vtkIOEnSight;vtkIOMySQL;vtkRenderingMatplotlib;vtkDomainsChemistry;vtkIOExport;vtkFiltersParallelMPI;vtkIOParallelXML;vtkTestingRendering;vtkIOMPIParallel;vtkParallelMPI4Py;vtkFiltersSMP;vtkFiltersSelection;vtkIOVPIC;VPIC;vtkImagingMath;vtkImagingMorphological;vtkRenderingParallel;vtkRenderingFreeTypeFontConfig;vtkIOFFMPEG;vtkIOMPIImage;vtkIOGDAL (Required is at least version "1.3") 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/matt/hdd_home/pcl/tutorials/build
```

As can quite easily been seen, what is outputted is very different to what is shown in the tutorial.

It does create a build file so I can run `make` which errors and outputs:

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pcd_write_test.dir/pcd_write.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable pcd_write_test
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkproj4
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/pcd_write_test.dir/build.make:330: recipe for target 'pcd_write_test' failed
make[2]: *** [pcd_write_test] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/pcd_write_test.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/pcd_write_test.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I've tried what I can but maybe I lack enough experience to get this all sorted and working.

I also manually installed the package `libproj-dev` which has been suggested  but this did not fix the issue.

**Any help would be much appreciated!**

Comment: Have you installed the dependencies listed here [Compiling PCL from source on POSIX compliant systems](http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/compiling_pcl_posix.php#compiling-pcl-posix) - in particular, `libvtkproj4` should be provided on Ubuntu 16.04 by package `libvtk5-dev`

Comment: @steeldriver, I have `libvtk6-dev` installed. When I install `libvtk5-dev` it causes `cmake` to completely error out and produce the following http://pastebin.com/kSaA9Ysw. Installing one removes the other.

Comment: As far as I can see, neither libvtk6.2 nor libvtk6-dev provide libvtkproj4. Perhaps cmake has cached something related to libvtk5? Have you tried starting over since you installed libvtk6-dev (if you used an out-of-tree cmake build directory, you can simply delete it)

Comment: @steeldriver, `libvtk6-dev` is bundled in `libpcl-dev` and that gives the initial `cmake` output I gave.  Am I right in thinking deleting the 'build' directory I created that the makefile is generated to will clear anything cached by `cmake`? If that's the case then I've cleared the cache and run with both `libvtk6` & `libvtk5`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installation is missing `python-vtk` which is available in the Ubuntu [repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/python-vtk).

This contains the required `libvtkRenderingPythonTkWidgets` package.

Installing it should remove the problem:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python-vtk
```

It did for me.